# can anyone help me to create a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I have too many fields on my page layout. i would like to hide some of them depending on the value in a picklist. So i have an object called Business review (based on case) and field Business Outcome with values Pass and Fail. Then I have Pass Reason and Fail reason fields. If business outcome value is Pass i would like to show only Pass reason field and hide Fail reason field. this is only an example but if someone could create a visualforce for me i could then change the values. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you attempted to create the Visualforce page yourself?

Comment: Ewa, I suspect it unlikely that anyone will develop a page from scratch for you. Instead, I recommend reading about basic VF syntax and learning on your own, and posting here if you encounter a **specific** problem that we can help you through.

Answer (score 6):

Try using RecordTypes!  RecordTypes allow you to display not only different pick list values, but different page layouts!  This solution relies on zero code, and yo don't have to worry about making code changes everytime a new field is needed or some business need changes.

We have 100+ fields, but change the recordtype based on a certain picklist value entered by users, which allows us to display only the ***relevant*** fields.

https://sci.my.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_recordtypes_cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should try taking a look at the Visualforce Workbook http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/workbook_vf.pdf . It is very helpful in getting started. A little goes a long way with the Visualforce Workbook. You can learn a lot in a few pages. Also the Trailhead site will help to teach you apex and visualforce https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules . There is a Visualforce Basics Module and a Visualforce Mobile Module.  When doing Visualforce I like to make sure that development mode is enabled on my user profile. This allows you to see changes while you work and it will automatically add the end tag.Also, On this site typically people want to see that you have made an attempt and you should post what you have tried to prevent people from voting your questions down or putting them on hold. Also if the requirement is to have a series of fields hidden based on a picklist field then Recordtypes wouldn't solve that, but Visualforce would. Especially if the record is already created when the user realizes that it is a pass or fail. You could also try the Skuid app if you are going the Visualforce app. This allows you to create custom Visualforce pages without having knowledge of how to write VF code. It is more "point and click" which makes it very user friendly. It is a paid app but it works very well and is fairly cheap. Last time I was at a place that had it, it was about 5 bucks per person and worth every penny if you need Visualforce done fast and without coding knowledge.